# Error: Missing binding "binding.node" after merge to main branch

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I tried to configure automated code coverage in CI/CD in one of my branches in GitLab, and the pipeline passed perfectly within the branch, but when the admin merged the changes into the main branch, the pipeline failed due to a missing binding.

I used `gitlab-ci.yml` to configure my jobs in. I didn't have any experience working with pipelines, so this was pretty much a trial and error task for me.

Finally I got the configuration that was working for me that didn't break anything and produced the coverage as required. However, since it was showing a **no space error** prior to a successful build, I had to force clear the cache to get the jobs to run properly. Within my branch, the pipeline passed without any errors and I double checked by re-running it several times. But once the admin merged the branch it suddenly started producing the following error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:72)
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:72)
    at runLoaders (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:244:20)
    at /builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:229:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:202:4)
    at Storage.finished (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
    at provider (/builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
    at /builds/internal/employee_portal/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:90:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**side note**: The branch I was working on had been checked out from the main branch, no changes from other branches had been included into this one.

I wanted to know:

- what part of my code caused this error (i suspect force clearing the cache, but just a hunch)
- why this error did not appear in the pipeline of the branch I was working in?
- why is the runner giving an error when it has bindings for an **updated** version of Node? Shouldn't it be backward compatible?

I've looked at [this link](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/185), but I'm curious as to why this error never occurred before merge and even if it did, why is it giving me an error because I have an **updated** version installed.

Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: trion/ng-cli-karma

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - npm cache clear --force
   - npm i @angular/cli
   - npm install
   - npm run generate-docs
   - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --base-href . --output-path www/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      -  www/
      -  documentation/
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --code-coverage=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
  coverage: '/(\d*.?\d+)%/'

pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
    - test
  script:
    - ls
    - mv documentation www/
    - mv coverage/ www/
    - mv www/ public
    - ls public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
```

Comment: Why are you installing the ng-cli, it is part of the docker image already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and `npm rebuild node-sass` command **didn't** work for me. The reason was the npm cache. If you clear the cache, issue would be resolved.

Steps followed:

- Remove node modules `rm -rf node_modules/`
- Remove cache `npm cache clean --force`
- Verify cache removed `npm cache verify`
- `npm install`